# Why do i get an Segmentation fault?

Tags: c, string, loops

I know it has to do with my for loop. Have tried to modify it, but whatever I put in for the arguments, I still get an Segmentation fault.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   char* request_target = "/cat.html?q=Alice hej";

   // TODO: extract query from request-target
   char query[20];

   // finds start of query
   char* startofquery = strstr(request_target, "q=");
   if (startofquery != NULL)
   {
       int j = 0;
       for (int i = strlen(request_target) - strlen(startofquery); i  == ' '; i++, j++)
       {
           query[j] = request_target[i];
       }
       request_target[j] = '\0';
   }
   else
   {
       printf("400 Bad Request");
   }

   printf("%s", query);
}
```

Comment: Segmentation Overflow?`

Comment: Could you provide some sample output with error message? I'm familiar with "Segmentation fault" and "Stack Overflow" (pun intended) but not Segmentation Overflow.

Comment: You calculate `int i` as a difference of lengths of two strings, then compare it to a space character `i == ' '`...?!

Comment: @SouravGhosh Segmentation fault, lol sry..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line defines a string literal

```
char* request_target = "/cat.html?q=Alice hej";
```

It is undefined behaviour to write to a string literal
you are doing that here :

```
request_target[j] = '\0';
```

use a char array instead

```
char request_target[] = "/cat.html?q=Alice hej";
```

Also, if I understand correctly you are trying to extract `q=Alice` from `/cat.html?q=Alice hej`. The for loop you implemented has a few issues (`i == ' '`) as mentioned in other answers. And is not actually necessary. You can copy this part quite simply:

```
char *startofquery = strstr(request_target, "q=");
char *endofquery = strchr(startofquery, ' ');
int querySize = endofquery - startofquery;
if (startofquery != NULL && endofquery != NULL) {
    memcpy(query, startofquery, querySize);
    query[querySize] = '\0';
}
```

This is less error prone and will most likely perform better. In this case you don't need to define `request_target` as an array but I would recommend to make it const so that you will get a useful compiler error if you attempt to write:

```
const char *request_target = "/cat.html?q=Alice hej";
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two points that I can see appears to be troublesome.

1. in your for loop, the terminating condition

   ```
   i  == ' '
   ```

   should be

   ```
   request_target[i] != ' '
   ```

   if you want to run the loop until it gets a space character, or,

   ```
   request_target[i] != '\0'
   ```

   if you would want to run the loop til the end of the source string.
2. `request_target[j] = '\0';` should be `query[j] = '\0';` because,

   1) You cannot modify a string literal, it's [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

   2) Probably you want to null terminate the destination array.

Comment: I think `i` is index in array and not char value. Comparing it `i == ' '` or `i != ' '` is like comparison to value 32. And it is changed at every iteration (i++)... The loop can run once. In other words, there is bug.

Comment: How would you then do if you want the loop to terminate once it hits an space character?

Comment: @i486 Thanks!! makes sense. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your for loop. The first one is the condition:

```
 for (int i = strlen(request_target) - strlen(startofquery); i  == ' '; i++, j++)
```

Here `i` is an integer (position in your string), but you are comparing against a char (`' '`). It should be:

```
for (int i = strlen(request_target) - strlen(startofquery); request_target[i]  != ' '; i++, j++)
```

The second problem is you're trying to write into a string literal (UB) here:

```
 request_target[j] = '\0';
```

It should be:

```
 query[j] = '\0';
```